# Set Action Class attribute using ajax jquery Struts-1

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, struts-1

I am facing issue in setting action class String through ajax call. Here is my code

DashBoardGraphAction.java

```
public class DashBoardGraphAction extends DispatchAction
{
   private String testString;


   public ActionForward getTransactionsByStatus(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                    throws Exception
    {   
       System.out.println(fromDate);
       return null;
     }

    public String getTestString() {
        return testString;
    }  
    public void setTestString(String testString) {
        this.testString = testString;
    }
```

Ajax call is as follows:

```
<script>
            var testString = "testName";
            $.ajax({

                url: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/gettransactionData.do?parameter=getTransactionsByStatus',

                type: 'POST',
                data: 'testString='+testString,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data)
                {       
                    str = data;
                },
                async:false,
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert('Error ' + textStatus);
                alert(errorThrown);
                alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                }
            });
 </script>
```

struts-config.xml

```
<action path="/gettransactionData" parameter="parameter"
    type="com.pp.dashboard.DashBoardGraphAction">
    <forward name = "getTransactionsByStatus" path = "/jsp/pp/dashboardReportStatus.jsp" /> 
    <forward name = "getTransactionsByProcessor" path = "/jsp/pp/dashboardReportProcessorWise.jsp" />
</action>
```

When action calls I am getting testString as null. I have tried my best to solve it but can't find what is missing. Any is is greatly appreciated.

Comment: where did you define your ActionForm i guess you are submitting  testString as a Post body? but i cannot see your Actionform defination in which action will populate this value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a your ActionForm class

```
 public class Person extends ActionForm {

        private String testString;

        public String getTestString() {
            return testString;
        }

        public void setTestString(String testString) {
            this.testString = testString;
        }



    }
```

Your Struts config will look like this

```
   <struts-config>
         <form-beans>

            <form-bean name="formClass" type="com.forms.Person"/>

        </form-beans>

        <action-mappings>



            <action name="formClass" path="/gettransactionData" parameter="parameter"
    type="com.pp.dashboard.DashBoardGraphAction">
    <forward name = "getTransactionsByStatus" path = "/jsp/pp/dashboardReportStatus.jsp" /> 
    <forward name = "getTransactionsByProcessor" path = "/jsp/pp/dashboardReportProcessorWise.jsp" />
</action>


        </action-mappings>

    </struts-config>
```

Change action class method like that

```
public ActionForward getTransactionsByStatus(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                    throws Exception
    {   
       Person p = (Person) form;
       System.out.println("Testing************************"+p.getTestString());
       return null;
     }
```

Check with these changes hopefully it will work